# Installing SQL Server 2005 - Performance Monitor Counter Requirement (Error)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, installation

when installing SQL Server 2005, I get this error. Can anyone tell me how to sort this out?

Thanks,
Optician

> - Performance Monitor Counter
>     Requirement (Error)
>
> Messages
>
> Performance Monitor Counter
>   Requirement   The System Configuration
>   Check for Performance Monitor counter
>   registry value has failed. For
>   details, see How to: Increment the
>   Counter Registry Key for Setup in SQL
>   Server 2005, in the readme file or in
>   SQL Server Books Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution addresses (from [here](http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f31/fix-error-performance-monitor-counter-requirement-when-installing-sql-2005-express-4512/)) your problem:

> Follow these steps to manually set the
>   increment for the counter registry key
>   & to overcome this error & proceed
>   further with the SQL Server
>   installation.
>
> 1. On the Microsoft Windows 2003 or Windows XP desktop, click Start, click
>      Run, type regedit.exe in Open, and
>      then click OK. On Windows 2000, use
>      regedt32.exe The Registry Editor
>      appliction launches.
> 2. Navigate to the following registry key: Quote: [HKEY _ LOCAL _
>      MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib] "Last
>      Counter"=dword:00000ed4 (5276)
>      "LastHelp"=dword:00000ed5 (5277)
> 3. The "Last Counter" value from the previous step (5276) must match the
>      maximum value of the "Counter" key
>      from "Perflib\009" in the following
>      registry key, and the "Last Help"
>      value from the previous step (5277)
>      must match the maximum value of the
>      "Help" key from "Perflib\009" in the
>      following registry key: Quote:
>      [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009] Note :
>      The "Last Counter" and "Last Help"
>      values are dynamically assigned by
>      Windows; they will vary from machine
>      to machine...
> 4. If necessary, modify the value for the "Last Counter" and "Last Help"
>      values in the "\Perflib" key:
>      Right-click "Last Counter" or "Last
>      Help" in the right-hand pane, click
>      Modify, click Base = "Decimal" set the
>      value in Value data, and then click
>      OK. Repeat for the other key, if
>      necessary, and then close the Registry
>      Editor.
> 5. Restart the machine for the changes to come into effect.
> 6. Run SQL Server Setup again.

This error seams to be related to the Setup Configuration Checker (SCC) in Microsoft SQL Server Setup which verifies the value of the counter registry key before SQL Server installation begins.

Comment: This is correct, but you dont have to restart the machine, at least I didn't

Comment: I'm glad to hear that this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked a google search on this error? (The System Configuration Check for Performance Monitor counter registry value has failed.)

[Article One](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32007538/performance-monitor-count.aspx)

[Article Two](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/549f01cd-839e-4a71-ac5e-66412ae0172b)

I note that the articles specify having to use Regedt32 to allow the fixes to work.